# Java - refresh opened html page from application

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I have an application that creates a html page from app (I use [freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)). After that, I open the generated webpage from application using Desktop like this:

```
public void openPage() {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                File file = new File("index.html");
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error opening a html page.");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, my question is: Is there a way to refresh the page from my application? I am changing the concent dynamically and I would like to refresh the page in the browser every few seconds.

Or would it be better to just update the page on background and refresh it directly in the html code using javascript?

Thanks for any tips!

EDIT: Note, that I would like to communicate back to my java application from some form on that webpage (for example sending parametres to specify the way my page is updated)

Comment: using ajax in webpage for partial page updation is better option

Comment: @MehulKaklotar Moreover, querying for data only without any kind of presentation logic or metadata (i.e. returning pure JSON and no HTML) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX technology (**[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)** pretty much fits your needs) to invoke a server side controller in your application. You can then negotiate the need for a data update. A JSON API is recommended for this. You can use **[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)** for JSON-related operations in your Java code.

To save bandwidth, you could poll for only a `boolean` value to determine whether the server has new data since your last update (e.g. provide `since=[some_timestamp]` as request param) and query for the actual data only if it makes sense (that is, the server returned `true`).

Comment: Rather than polling for a boolean value, you could make a request using the modified-since header or etags. If implemented on the server, it'll return a 304 not modified response which you can deal with in your browser.

Comment: Would be pretty cool, but your business logic shouldn't be dependent on the server it is running on. You could of course poll for a "business logic equivalent" of the *modified-since* header as well but my point here was suggesting a possible solution, not listing them all :) You're welcome to add anything constructive to the post as you like.